Does Java Object class contain a collection for keeping track of threads waiting on them?
How exactly is wait() and notify() implemented in Java?
When a thread calls wait() on an object, does the object store the threads in a collection within the object? So that when notify() is called, it can wake up the thread waiting on it

From a language perspective, it's unspecified. I have no idea how any of the JVMs do it, though I'm sure it includes constructs supported by the OS and down to the hardware level.

From the Java Language Specification 17.2:

Every object, in addition to having an associated monitor, has an associated wait set. A wait set is a set of threads.

So each object has a set of threads waiting on it.
Also from 17.2, calling Object.wait() will add the active thread to that object's wait set:

Wait sets are manipulated solely through the methods Object.wait, Object.notify, and Object.notifyAll.

Sections 17.2.1 and 17.2.2 have more details about wait and notification work.
The JLS doesn't describe anything further about how this is implemented.
